# "Fatal error: QUdpSocket: No such file or directory" in VSCode

Tags: c++, qt, udp

I'm struggling with my C++ code because I'm kind of new with big projects and the use of CMake.

I'm having that compilation problem and I don't know how to solve it because all the solutions online are using QtCreator, but I'm using VS Code.

**compilation problem**

```
In file included from /home/icksir/Documentos/robocup/sysmic-project/libs/vision/src/main.cpp:1:
/home/icksir/Documentos/robocup/sysmic-project/libs/vision/src/../include/vision.hpp:3:10: fatal error: QUdpSocket: No existe el archivo o el directorio
    3 | #include <QUdpSocket>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libs/vision/src/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:76: libs/vision/src/CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:192: libs/vision/src/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

**my project**

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
│   ├── behavior
│   ├── communication
│   ├── navigation   
│   ├── planning  
│   ├── referee    
│   ├── trainer     
│   └── vision
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── docs
│       │   └── requirements.txt
│       ├── external
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   ├── proto
│       │   │   ├── messages_robocup_ssl_detection.proto
│       │   │   ├── messages_robocup_ssl_geometry.proto
│       │   │   └── messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.proto
│       │   └── proto_compiled
│       │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_detection.pb.cc
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_detection.pb.h
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_geometry.pb.cc
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_geometry.pb.h
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.pb.cc
│       │       └── messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.pb.h
│       ├── include
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   └── vision.hpp
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   ├── main.cpp
│       │   └── vision.cpp
│       └── tools
│           └── protobuf.bash
├── LICENSE
└── README.md
```

**vision.hpp**

```
#ifndef VISION_H
#define VISION_H
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QObject>
#include "messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.pb.h"

class Vision: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Vision(QObject *parent);
        void initSocket();
        int port_grsim = 10020;
        void processPendingDatagrams();
        SSL_WrapperPacket packet;

    private:
        QUdpSocket *socket=nullptr;
};

#endif
```

**vision.cpp**

```
#include "vision.hpp"

Vision::Vision(QObject *parent) : 
    QObject(parent) {
}

void Vision::initSocket(){
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    bool result =  socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, this->port_grsim);
    if(result){
        qDebug() << "Socket PASS";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Socket FAIL";
    }

    processPendingDatagrams();
    connect(socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &Vision::processPendingDatagrams);
}

void Vision::processPendingDatagrams(){
    qDebug() << "in !";
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 port;
    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size(),&sender,&port);
        qDebug() <<"Message From :: " << sender.toString();
        qDebug() <<"Port From :: "<< port;
        qDebug() <<"Message :: " << datagram;
    }
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt** in /vision/src

```
project(SysmicEngine)

add_library(Vision vision.cpp)

#public: quien tenga acceso a Vision tiene acceso a los includes
target_include_directories(Vision
    PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/proto_compiled)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Network)
target_link_libraries(Vision PRIVATE Qt6::Network)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main
    PRIVATE
    Vision
)
```

I don't know what file else could also be needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not simply search for the file `QUdpSocket` in the Qt installation directory? Is it installed in a subdirectory that you're not adding the path to? Have it been installed at all? Perhaps you need to reinstall Qt with more modules enabled?

Comment: Also, I recommend you create a much smaller test-project where you can experiment and test things, to make sure everything works before adding them to the larger main project.

Comment: I installed qt from the command `$ sudo apt-get install qt6-base-dev`. How could I search the file there? I'm really used to Python, so everything here in C++ is really confusing for me.

Comment: Perhaps [this documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html#building-a-c-console-application), about using Qt with CMake, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I didn't install properly Qt6 from source code, because CMake for Qt needed the last version that Ubuntu didn't offer. Thanks to Some programmer dude because Qt6 has a really good documentation to create projects with CMake.

Answer (score 2):

As you've used `PRIVATE` in `target_link_libraries`, targets which link to `Vision` won't inherit any settings from the Qt target. Either use `PUBLIC` or you'll need to link `main` to `Qt6::Network` too.